Python3 multiprocessing.Manager failed when running in 'old' docker on ubuntu18
Have a situation where I need to deploy my app on the ubuntu18.04 host having docker 19.03.13.
Both are fare from newest but atm I can't update any of them.
When I try to run my python app it constantly crashed with some multiprocessing related exception. Tried to narrow down and came up with the only two line program:
from multiprocessing import Manager
Manager().dict()

Tried different python3 images but all I tried failed with either:

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Python 3.12.8 (main, Dec  4 2024, 20:39:47) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from multiprocessing import Manager
>>> Manager().dict()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 726, in temp
    token, exp = self._create(typeid, *args, **kwds)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 606, in _create
    conn = self._Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 525, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 953, in answer_challenge
    message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 430, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 395, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

or

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Python 3.10.16 (main, Dec  4 2024, 20:37:22) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from multiprocessing import Manager
>>> Manager().dict() 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 723, in temp
    token, exp = self._create(typeid, *args, **kwds)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 606, in
_create
    conn = self._Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 502, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 630, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tried to run above two lines within the interpreter within the docker started as:

docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash python:VERSION

Most of the version I've tried failed with the above exceptions.
The only one seems to work for me was python:3.8.2
Also when running same on other machines (with newer both OS and docker) - all works fine on any python version.
So the question is - how can I make python 3.10+ works properly on that 'old' machine without updating OS and docker on it?

Show us the full error traceback.

added to the initial descr
